# Need help finding elementary lower triangular matricies

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the matrix $$A= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 1  \\
-1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 4   \end{array} \right) $$
I need to find the elementary lower triangular matricies $L_1(m^1)$ and $L_2(m^2)$. As far as I understand it, I want to find $L_1(m^1)$ and $L_2(m^2)$ such that $$L_1(m^1)L_2(m^2)A=U
$$Where U is an upper triangular 3x3 matrix which I found to be $$U= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 1  \\
0 & 3 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 12   \end{array} \right)$$ My attempt led me to find $$m^1=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0   \\
1  \\
-2    \end{array} \right), m^2=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0   \\
0  \\
-\frac{2}{3}    \end{array} \right)  $$ But when I compute $L_1(m^1)$ and $L_2(m^2)$ using the formula and try and verify my answer is right I dont get $U$, I dont even get an upper triangular matrix. As I understand it this is a simple task but I cant find anything online that gives an example similar to this one. If someone could give me some pointers it would be great

Comment: I don't get your notation:  What do you mean by $L_1(\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 1\\ -2 \end{array}\right))$?

Comment: apologies. I mean that $L_1(m^1)=I-m^1e_1^T$

Comment: Anyone? I have been stuck for ages